# qpdfview command-line argument for forward search

Tags: linux, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf, command-line, qpdfview

With sumatrapdf, I use the following command to go to the pdf place corresponding to the line 304 of the TeX source file:

`sumatrapdf file.pdf -forward-search file.tex 304`

What is the analogue command with qpdfview in a linux terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution:

```
qpdfview --unique file.pdf#src:file.tex:304:0 &
```