# Evince: how to do a forward-search from Terminal?

Tags: linux, forward-inverse-search, evince, command-line, qpdfview

Assume that I have produced a `pdf` file from a `tex` document with the option `\synctex=1` with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

Various forward-search methods tell us how to jump from your text editor to the corresponding place in evince pdf viewer.

Assuming a specific line-number of the source TeX file is given, is there a method to go to the corresponding place of pdf file in evince from Terminal in Linux?

More explicitly how to jump from Terminal to evince to the place corresponding to a specific line (say line 304) of the TeX source file?

Something like:

```
evince --some-args myfile.pdf --some-args myfile.tex -line 304
```

For qpdfview one can do the following:

```
qpdfview --unique myfile.pdf#src:myfile.tex:304:0 &
```

See [qpdfview command-line argument for forward search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588221/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no command line option for Evince to provide a synctex line number. However, if the pdf file is already opened in Evince, you can call the Evince daemon directly via dbus to execute the `SyncView` library command. From the terminal:

```bash
gdbus call --session --dest :[id] --object-path /org/gnome/evince/Window/0 --method org.gnome.evince.Window.SyncView "[file.tex]" "([line], 1)" "0"
```

Here, `[id]` is the identifier of the current Evince instance for the pdf file, `[file.tex]` is the source file and `[line]` is the line number. Note that the `[]` are to indicate placeholders, they are not part of the actual command.

Of course this terminal command is very impractical, because Evince already needs to be open, and you need to know the id, which requires other `dbus` calls. Therefore it is easier to write some wrapper code. The Python library `dbus` for example exposes the dbus methods for finding the id and executing the sync in a more user-friendly way.

The code below is slightly adapted (to accept command line arguments) from https://github.com/PHPirates/evince_dbus. This is also the source for the terminal command discussed above, and the repository contains example code for other programming languages that expose `dbus` as well.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Source: https://github.com/PHPirates/evince_dbus/blob/master/python/evince_forward_search_minimal.py
# Copyright (C) 2010 Jose Aliste <jose.aliste@gmail.com>
#               2011 Benjamin Kellermann <Benjamin.Kellermann@tu-dresden.de>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
# the terms of the GNU General Public Licence as published by the Free Software
# Foundation; either version 2 of the Licence, or (at your option) any later
# version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public Licence for more
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public Licence along with
# this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin
# Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA

# This file offers forward search for evince.
import os
from traceback import print_exc

import dbus
import sys
import time

line_number = int(sys.argv[1])
pdf_file = os.getcwd() + '/' + sys.argv[2] + ".pdf"
tex_file = os.getcwd() + '/' + sys.argv[2] + ".tex"

try:
    # Initialize a session bus
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()

    # Get a reference to the evince daemon object
    daemon = bus.get_object('org.gnome.evince.Daemon', '/org/gnome/evince/Daemon')

    # findDocument is a method provided by Evince on the dbus, see
    # https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-July/msg02054.html
    # "It returns the name owner of the evince process for the given document
    #  URI."
    dbus_name: str = daemon.FindDocument('file://' + pdf_file, True, dbus_interface="org.gnome.evince.Daemon")
    print("evince process owner: " + dbus_name)  # Something like :1.149
    time.sleep(0.5) # small delay to allow Evince to start up before syncing. Could probably be set even smaller.
    # Get the window remote object
    window = bus.get_object(dbus_name, '/org/gnome/evince/Window/0')

    # Call a method on the object: highlight a line in the pdf
    window.SyncView(tex_file, (line_number, 1), 0, dbus_interface="org.gnome.evince.Window")
except dbus.DBusException:
    print_exc()
```

Now, given the following LaTeX file `myfile.tex` compiled with `synctex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Example section}
regular contents
\newpage
\section{New page}
with some contents
\end{document}
```

and the following command (arguments: line number, base name of the file):

```bash
python3 evince_forward_search.py 6 myfile
```

Evince opens the file and jumps to the second page and shows the Synctex border:

[image]

Of course you can make this a bit more user-friendly by making the `.py` file executable and put it in the path.

Note that when I was trying out the code it did not work 100% of the time when starting with Evince closed. The viewer always started and the pdf file was shown, however on some occasions there was no sync. In those cases however running the command again while Evince was still open would reliably show the sync. Therefore I suspect that there is a timing issue when opening the pdf where the id is already returned but the process does not accept interactions yet. I have added 0.5 seconds delay before performing the sync. This is a bit distracting as Evince visibly jumps to the right location, and it is also not necessary when Evince is already open, so you might want to remove this or make the delay shorter - but it does seem to solve the occasional issue where the sync is not performed.

---

Remark: Evince itself has a `--named-dest` command line flag, see `man evince` (or an [online man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-evince/)). This flag can be used to jump to sections in the document that have a named anchor, which is for example generated by the `hyperref` package. An example is:

```bash
evince --named-dest=section.2.1 myfile.pdf &
```

However, Synctex does not generate this type of anchors, instead it stores the raw grid positions of the source lines in the `synctex.gz` file - therefore the `--named-dest` flag cannot be used for this.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. However, I am able to do a forward-search from emacs to evince. When I fire the above command, the pdf file is opened at the page 1.

Comment: @Name indeed I didn't test my previous answer with Synctex itself - I assumed the anchors would be the same but this is not the case. See the edit for an approach that I actually _did_ test with Synctex :)

Comment: Thank you very much, should I install some dependencies / softwares  before using `evince --named-dest=section.2.1 myfile.pdf &`?  When I run this command, I get the error `File "evince_forward_search.py", line 44
    dbus_name: str = daemon.FindDocument('file://' + pdf_file, True, dbus_interface="org.gnome.evince.Daemon")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @Name I think you are mixing the commands a bit. The `named-dest` part is not part of the answer. As you had noticed this does not work for Synctex, so for your question you can completely ignore the part below the horizontal line. I just left it in as extra information about Evince, because maybe other people that are not interested in Synctex but are interested in named destinations will find this question.

Comment: @Name now for the Python code, you need to run this with Python 3, so you type `python3 evince_forward_search.py 6 yourfile` in the terminal (assuming that you saved the Python code in a file named `evince_forward_search.py`, and that your file is called `yourfile.pdf`). If you run it with Python 2 (using `python2 evince_forward_search.py` but probably using `python evince_forward_search.py`, because `python` is still aliased to `python2` on many systems) then you get the syntax error.

Comment: If you make it executable then you probably need to change the top line of the code into `#!/usr/bin/python3` to run the correct Python version.

Comment: @Name I also added a `sleep(0.5)` delay in the code just now, it seems that makes the approach more reliable (see also the edit in the answer itself for more discussion).